# Extensão para listagem TODO no VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, extensão

É possível listar os TODO em meu código utilizando o vscode?

Answer (score 0):

Sim. Comentários deste tipo não têm absolutamente nada a ver com a linguagem, são recursos dos editores de texto ou IDEs, portanto não faz diferença se você está usando TypeScript ou não.

No VS Code você pode instalar diversas extensões (inclusive, este é um dos motivos do sucesso do editor).

Uma extensão que faz isso que deseja é a [TODO Parser](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=minhthai.vscode-todo-parser). Ela mostra a quantidade dos comentários na barra inferior e na janela de *output* e você pode configurá-la para mostrar os comentários na janela de problemas.

Veja como fica:

[image: TODOS na lista de problemas do VS Code]

Uma extensão de visualização deste tipo que eu gosto bastante é a [Todo Tree](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gruntfuggly.todo-tree). Ela tem um painel lateral para mostrar as listas.

[image: Lista de TODOS na barra lateral]

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @WellingtonDeSouzaFilho Você pode marcar a resposta como correta usando o V do lado esquerdo.